# C on GNU/Linux, replace terminal strings

Tags: linux, shell, terminal

Actually when i open the terminal i got this default string:
`username@hostname:~`

I want to replace the above string whit this one:
`<myprgrogram>:~`

How can i do this?
I'm developing in C on GNU/Linux).
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is `<myprgrogram>` the current path?

Comment: no no <myprogram> is the program's name!

Comment: @polslinux - which program name ? If it's the program that's *running* then you won't have a prompt whilst it's running (unless you background it)

Comment: What is the relation between your problem and programming in C? The string you see when you log in (_open the terminal_) is the shell prompt.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set up your prompt as detailed [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-linux-unix-bash-shell-setup-prompt.html) (I'm assuming you're using `bash`).

There are *numerous* options and capabilities. See [here](http://jamiedubs.com/ps1-collection-customize-your-bash-prompt/) for a gallery of examples.

Comment: Something like: `system("PS1='[myprogram:$]\'");`

Answer (score 0):

If you mean current path, then add the below line to your `.bashrc` file.

```
export PS1='<$PWD>:'
```

Comment: i mean that when the **C** program will start its execution it has to change the PS1 from `username@hostame` to `<program_name>` :)

Comment: And when the C program starts, the shell is suspended until your program completes.  Your program and the shell are two separate processes, and neither can change data in the other's memory.

Answer (score 0):

You can change an environmental variable using setenv/putenv from the standard library (stdlib.h), see "man setenv".
However, when the program ends the variable won't be saved.